# Why are these two function types in typescript different?

Tags: function, typescript, types, typescript-2.5

Using typescript, I'm finding why two different functions assigned to different local variables result in different signatures.  I thought one was just more explicit.

```
let a: (number)=>number =
  function(x: number): number {return 42;};

let z = function(x:number): number { return 42; };

> .type a
let a: (number: any) => number
> .type z
let z: (x: number) => number
```

I thought `a` was just a more explicit version of writing `z`, but somehow it gets typed more liberally as accepting `any`.

Using Typescript version 2.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let a: (number)=>number
```

The parameter name is required. This is exactly equivalent to:

```
let a: (number: any)=>number
```

In other words, the first `number` here defines *a parameter named "number"*

What you need is,

```
let a: (x: number)=>number =
  function(x: number): number {return 42;};
```

The name, `x`, doesn't matter.

Comment: ah, so you have name it, or it's assumed to be a name with a type of any. That's pretty stupid. And, the name doesn't doesn't matter for the purposes of typechecking?

Comment: The name doesn't matter

Comment: FWIW: It needs to be that way to maintain compatibility with JavaScript.